# Expressing tangent curve via level surface and graph of function

Tags: differential-geometry

Given the sphere of radius $2$ centered at $(2,-1,0)$, find an equation for the plane tangent to it at the point $(1,0,\sqrt{2})$ in the following ways:

1) by considering the sphere as the graph of the function
$f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{4-(x-2)^{2}-(y+1)^{2}}$

2) by considering the sphere as a level surface of the function
$F(x,y,z)=(x-2)^{2}+(y+1)^{2}+z^{2}$

I am so lost that I do not know how to get the ball rolling on the question. Worst still, I do not know which areas I should be reading up on.

Thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

To find a plane, you need to know a point that it passes through, and its normal vector. We have the point -- it's $P=(1, 0, \sqrt2)$, so now we need the normal. But the normal of the tangent plane is the same as the normal of the surface at $P$. Have you learned any techniques for finding the normal at a point on a surface? That would be a good place to start reading.

And, although you're not supposed to do the problem this way, the answer is obvious, geometrically. The required normal vector must be in the direction from the center of the sphere to the point $P$, i.e. in the direction $N = (1, 0, \sqrt2) - (2, -1, 0)$. So, the equation of the tangent plane is $(X -P)\cdot N = 0$. You can use this to check your answers.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent space to a level set $F=const$ at a point $p\in\mathbb R^3$ is the $\ker dF_p$,  $\{X=[u,v,w]^T\in\mathbb R^3:dF_p(X)=0\}$.

For example, for $F(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and a given point $p(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ we have $[2x\,dx+2y\,dy+2z\,dz]\vert_p(X)=0$. Or, $x_0\cdot u+y_0\cdot v+z_0 \cdot w=0$, which is the equation of a plane with the origin at p in local coordinates. In the ambient $\mathbb R^3$ the same plane is described as $x_0\cdot (x-x_0)+y_0\cdot (y-y_0)+z_0 \cdot (z-z_0)=0$